# Máscara javascript está quebrando se eu digitar a data rapidamente

Tags: javascript, react

Estou tentando fazer uma máscara de data javascript para usar no react com formato dd/mm/yyyy para um componente personalizado de seleção de data.

Se eu pressiono as teclas devagar, a máscara aplica corretamente o formato, porém se eu pressionar os números rapidamente, a máscara é quebrada, não adicionando os '/'

Meu componente:

```
<DateInput
       name="date"
       placeholder="Data"
       value={this.props.data}
       dateFormat="DD/MM/YYYY"
       onChange={this.props.changeDataTarefa}
       animation="none"
       onKeyUp={() => this.props.changeDataTarefaMask(this.fixDatePattern(this.props.data))}/>
```

Minhas funções:

```
 fixDatePattern(currDate) {
        var currentDate = currDate;
        if (currentDate){
            var currentLength = currentDate.length;
            var lastNumberEntered = currentDate[currentLength - 1];
        }

        if (!this.isNumber(lastNumberEntered) && currentDate) {
          return currentDate.substring(0, currentLength - 1);
        }

        if (currentLength > 10) {
          return currentDate.substring(0, 10);
        }
        let dateCountTracker = 0

        if (currentLength == 1 && currentDate > 1) {
          var transformedDate = "0" + currentDate + '/';
          dateCountTracker = 2;
          currentLength = transformedDate.length;
          return transformedDate;
        } else if (currentLength == 4 && currentDate[3] > 3) {
          let transformedDate = currentDate.substring(0, 3) + "0" + currentDate[3] + '/';
          dateCountTracker = 5;
          currentLength = transformedDate.length;
          return transformedDate;
        } else if (currentLength == 2 && (dateCountTracker != 2 && dateCountTracker != 3)) {
          dateCountTracker = currentLength;
          return currentDate + '/';
        } else if (currentLength == 5 && (dateCountTracker != 5 && dateCountTracker != 6)) {
          dateCountTracker = currentLength;
          return currentDate + '/';
        }

        dateCountTracker = currentLength;
        return currentDate;
      }

    isNumber(n) {
        return !isNaN(parseFloat(n)) && isFinite(n);
      }
```

Porque isso ocorre?

Comment: Oi Veronese, poderia a função changeDataTarefa? me parece que está ocorrendo um problema ao setar o estado. A sua função de checar a data digitada poderia estar antes de invocar a changeDataTarefa. Deixa eu ver como está e te respondo melhor.

Answer (score 0):

Eu acredito que você deva usar `onKeyPress` ao invés de `onKeyUp`:

```
<DateInput
       name="date"
       placeholder="Data"
       value={this.props.data}
       dateFormat="DD/MM/YYYY"
       onChange={this.props.changeDataTarefa}
       animation="none"
       onKeyPress={() => this.props.changeDataTarefaMask(this.fixDatePattern(this.props.data))}/>
```